# Ubuntu 18.04 network-manager not working

Tags: internet-connection, ubuntu-18.04

I am not able to use internet on Ubuntu 18.04 because network-manager is not running

When I try `sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start` or restart, it gives following error

[....] Starting network-manager (via systemctl): network-manager.serviceJob for NetworkManager.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status NetworkManager.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

After that the command  `systemctl status NetworkManager.service` prints several lines and prints "Failed to start Network Manager." several times.

What can be done?

Comment: What dies Journalcta say?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I had made changes to the /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf because my wifi was getting shut down within some time.

I don't remember what was the default value but I'd removed everything in it and replaced it by (only) 2. So network manger was complaining that it is not a correct key value pair and hence was not starting.

I replaced it to

`[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3`

and now it is working.